# Website blocking issue in squid3 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, squid, acl

I am trying to block some websites on my ubuntu 12.04 with Squid 3.1.19. Following is a view of my ACL's.`

## Denying domains based on defind access list

```
acl ym dstdomain .yahoo.com  microsoft.com facebook.com youtube.com
http_access deny ym
```

with above mentioned script, it is not working. 
Remember! squid3.conf is opened in gedit editor.
Please guide where i am wrong?

Comment: This question is specific to an end of life Ubuntu release. These are no longer supported and are therefore off-topic here.

Comment: Please include the log that shows the request the client sent. That said - do upgrade. 3.1.19 is ancient, and lacks support for modern web standards.

Comment: i need to update my squid? how? sorry i am new to squid

Comment: how i can access to log in ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: @vidarlo here look at my log file                                                        home@ubuntu:~$ sudo squid3 cache.log
[sudo] password for home: 
2018/01/01 23:41:49| WARNING: (A) '192.168.1.0/24' is a subnetwork of (B) '192.168.0.0/16'
2018/01/01 23:41:49| WARNING: because of this '192.168.1.0/24' is ignored to keep splay tree searching predictable
2018/01/01 23:41:49| WARNING: You should probably remove '192.168.1.0/24' from the ACL named 'localnet'

Answer (score 1):

If we read the [caveat that is listed in Squid's documentation](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice):

> At no point during ssl_bump processing will dstdomain ACL work. That ACL relies on HTTP message details that are not yet decrypted. An ssl::server_name acl type is provided instead that uses CONNECT, SNI, or server certificate Subject name (whichever is available).

`dstdomain` simply checks the `Host:`-header sent by the client. This is not available for a SSL/TLS session.

We also see the following in the [ACL configuration documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/), under New in Squid 3.5:

> New types ssl::server_name and ssl::server_name_regex to match server name from various sources (CONNECT authority name, TLS SNI domain, or X.509 certificate Subject Name).

So squid >3.5 supports SNI inspection, and can block based on HTTPS certificates and SNI. Squid 3.1 cannot.

The full ACL documentation can be found at http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/

You need to upgrade to a newer squid version, and a newer Ubuntu relase. You can not expect five year old software to work in a fast changing environment like the internet is.